# jaxws:wsgen: goal not generating stubs

Tags: java, web-services, maven, wsimport

I am trying to build a web service client.  I am using maven 3.0.5 to manage my project and I would like to use the wsimport goal to generate my client stubs.  I have read through examples of how to configure the pom to achieve this [here](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/).  When I run an mvn clean install my stubs are not generated.  Below is my pom and an excerpt from the output of running mvn -X clean install.  I am trying to use the org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons version of the plugin since the org.codehaus.mojo version is old.  Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?  Thank you.

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.group.app</groupId>
<artifactId>ProjectName</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>ProjectName Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>ProjectName</finalName>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>basic</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <packageName>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/client_support</packageName>
                    <wsdlLocation>http://localhost:8080/wsdlLocation</wsdlLocation>
                    <destDir>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes/</destDir>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <target>2.1</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>

</build>
```

Here is part of the output from running an mvn -X clean install:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ProjectName Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin version for org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml in local (/home/michael/.m2/repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin version for org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin to 2.3.1-b03 from repository central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)
```

Here is an excerpt from my tomcat log file for when I try to deploy the service.

```
Jun 18, 2014 11:47:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletException: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: runtime modeler error:
Wrapper class path.to.jaxws.FaultBean is not found. Have you run APT to generate them? at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5204)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5199)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModelerException: runtime modeler error:
Wrapper class path.to.jaxws.FaultBean is not found. Have you run APT to generate them?
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getClass(RuntimeModeler.java:287)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processExceptions(RuntimeModeler.java:1006)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processRpcMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:969)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:546)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:371)
at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:258)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:322)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:188)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:467)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parseAdapters(DeploymentDescriptor    Parser.java:253)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.DeploymentDescriptorParser.parse(DeploymentDescriptorParser.j    ava:147)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServlet    ContextListener.java:108)
... 7 more
```

After running the mvn -X clean install the project builds successfully, however, neither the support stubs nor the package that contains then is created.  Thank you for your help.